# Qt and OpenCV Console App Error

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, console

I have compiled and run my codes without any error. However when I tried to change my code about the threshold function to adapthreshold, my app is building but can't run, there is only a console, not seen any error any crash.

Then repeat I remove the adapthreshold to threshold the app is working.

Here is my code :

```
adaptiveThreshold(dst,dst_gray,255,ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,THRESH_BINARY,15,2);
# Not error, can be built, Not any crash but not running 

threshold(dst,dst_gray,12.0,255.0,THRESH_BINARY);
# It can be built, working and running
```

Comment: so what does this question have to do with Qt?

Comment: Why qt can build but not run that function ?

Comment: Qt does not build anything.